# Homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}[i] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

We want to find all the ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}[i] $.

Let $φ:\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}[i] $ be a homomorphism.

We have $φ(1)=φ(1\cdot1)=φ(1)φ(1)\impliesφ(1)=0$ or $ φ(1)=1 $.
Βut $\sqrt{2} \mapstoφ(\sqrt{2})=a+bi$. So, $φ(2)=φ(1+1)=2φ(1) \ \text{and} \ φ(2)=φ(\sqrt{2})^2=a^2-b^2+2abi.$

And from this we have that $2φ(1)=a^2-b^2+2abi$.

If $φ(1)=0$ we have the trivial homomorphism and if $φ(1)=1,\ a^2=2,$ contradiction.

To sum up the only homomorphism is the trivial. Is this proof right or I missed something?

Comment: Homomorphims of what kind of structure? Abelian group? rng? ring? field?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The ring homomorphisms. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. One could summarise it as follows: since the equation $(\sqrt{2})^2-2=0$ holds in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, applying $\phi \neq 0$ gives the equation 
$$
0=\phi(0)=\phi(\sqrt{2})^2-\phi(2)=\phi(\sqrt{2})^2-2,
$$
so that $\phi(2)\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}]$ satisfies the equation $x^2-2=0$. This implies $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}[-1]$, which is impossible.

Comment: Is this enough to proove? Thank you.